# Android Phonegap app + AngularJS: Update $scope with selected date on android DatePicker

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope

I created a plugin for my phonegap app, which calls a native android "DatePicker" controll. The DatePicker is invoked in this way:

There is a checkbox on the view. When the user check's the checkbox, I invoke the DatePicker. After selecting a date and pressing confirm, an event is fired an I get the date selected. The problem is, inside this event, I don't have the $scope. Even though I try to set it and it does not get updated. I imagine that this happen because the $scope is not in the context when the event is fired.

I need to have the date that the user selected to make some validation, and allow he to save the changes. Here is my view and controller:

View (shortned for simplification purpose)

```
    <div>
        <span>Status</span> <br />
        <label>
            <!-- When this checkbox is checked, I invoke the DatePicker-->
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="resolved" ng-click="openCalendar()">
            <div ></div>Item Resolved
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <button ng-disabled="!resolved">Save</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
myappControllers.controller('ItemDetailsController', 
['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Notification', function ($scope, $routeParams, Notification) {

$scope.notification= Notification.getNotification($routeParams.Id);

$scope.resolved = false;

$scope.date = '';

//This event is fired when the user check's the checkbox
$scope.openCalendar = function(){ 

    // defining options
    var options = {
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date'
    };

    //This event is fired when the user has selected a date on the DatePicker
    datePicker.show(options, function(date){ 

        $scope.date = date //Does not get updated!

    });
}

//Function for save button
$scope.save = function(){

   if($scope.date){
      //save the changes
   }
}

}]);
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: Hi @jpgassi , it seems that we are using the same plugin :) - https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker , but I am not being able to invoke the calendar in the application - it is complaining about `show` action not defined. I have installed it by running `phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker` . Is there anything more I should do before building an phonegap app ? and is there a way to test this in a browser ? (as I am doing the development in the chrome before building into eclipse)

Comment: Hi. I ended up creating a plugin from scratch specific for my needs. I particularly don't like adding plugins via the command line. Since phonegap 3.0 it is kind of broke and I had several issues with it, so I prefer adding them manually. I would try inspecting the plugin's js file definition to see how is the show method created. Also check if the CLI added the plugin definition in the res/xml/config.xml file. If everything looks fine and still does not work, try removing the plugin and adding it manually. Check these links: http://bit.ly/1dgwGcY http://bit.ly/1fS6wlE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add $scope.$apply() to your  datePicker.show method.

```
datePicker.show(options, function(date){ 

    $scope.date = date;
    $scope.$apply();

});
```

Angular doesn't know about the change because it happens "outside", $scope.$apply() would fire a digest cycle so it can apply the changes.

Comment: Funny thing. I tried calling $apply in the show function yesterday and  I always got an undefined error. Anyway, works now. Thank you!