# How to use plugins for PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I have created an PhoneGap application using html and css. Now I wanted to add few things more and I have found a plugin for my next update to the app, but I have never used plugins for PhoneGap and I need a help, and I haven't find an example on the internet.

I am using PhoneGap `3.3.0`

I have installed a pluging that I needed from [DatePicker](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) . I have used the command:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker
```

Ok, it created new directory in `Plugins` but I don't know how to use the plugin. Maybe this is a silly question.

**What should I do?** - should I include some javascript into my code, update config.xml, update Java code or something similar to show this "date picker" when I click on a button in Html ? (for example)

I am using this for both `Android` and `iOS`. Also I don't know what is the differance between cordova and phonegap, as I can see they are both used (and I have taught that is one the same, but it seems it is not)

Comment: Goto the repo: https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker and read the 'Usages' section. It shows how to use the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen that. It doesn't say much should I change the config.xml, how to use it html, and what should I put in the html to invoke the datepicker on some input :/

Comment: @Aleks were you able to figure this out, id like a sample if so. thanks!

Comment: @alphapilgrim Hm, I don't really remember now, but I have solved it, but can't remember how. I can see I have posted a comment on a first answer and relating to other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601760/android-phonegap-app-angularjs-update-scope-with-selected-date-on-android-da Maybe it could help you

Comment: Also @alphapilgrim I don't get the `i'd like a sample` part. Hm, I would like a million dollars :)

Answer (score 3):

**What I want to happen is simple - I just want a datepicker to display when I click a certain field.**

However, the same as Aleks, I don't know what to put in my html, how to use it in html, and what should I put in the html to invoke the datepicker on some input.

The documentation from the [plugin](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) is incomplete.

I found a solution from this [test project](https://github.com/DURK/cordova-datepicker-plugin-test-project).
Steps are as follows:

1. Pre-requisite: **phonegap/cordova-cli installed**
2. Install Cordova's **device** plugin: `$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`
3. Install Dirk's **datepicker** plugin: `$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/DURK/cordova-datepicker-plugin`
4. Copy the [nativedatepicker.js](https://github.com/DURK/cordova-datepicker-plugin-test-project/blob/master/www/js/nativedatepicker.js) from the test project and place it on your project's **js** folder. This file has `showDatePicker(), showDateTimePicker()` convenience functions.
5. Add the ff. to `index.html` code:

**Note: The datepicker won't show when you test it in your browser**

```html
....
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Appointment</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="appointment">
    </div>
....
<script src="js/nativedatepicker.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function () {
                showDatePicker($(this), 'date');
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.timepicker', function () {
                showDatePicker($(this), 'time');
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.datetimepicker', function () {
                if (device.platform === "Android")
                    showDateTimePicker($(this));
                else
                    showDatePicker($(this), 'datetime');
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: The datepicker won't show up with this, I tap on the field and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

as dawson mentioned, over at https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker#usage, you can see how the plugin is used:

```
var options = {
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date'
};

datePicker.show(options, function(date){
  alert("date result " + date);  
});
```

this will of course need to go into your javascript.

if you have already added the platforms (iOS and Android), your **native** plugin files probably won't get copied into the platforms folder. in this case, you need to copy them manually. for iOS, the plugin files go into platforms/ios//Plugins.

regarding cordova/phonegap, think of cordova as the engine that powers phonegap. the codebase is the same so right now, most of the commands are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @urz0r, but sorry if I don't follow. It is not clear to me still what should I copy and the usage I have already seen on the github. My plugins folder is already created in the root , and I have a plugin defined there and also a android.json which  included the plugin automatically.

Comment: first things first: you don't have to change anything in your HTML or config.xml or anything like that. adding the plugin via command line will do the config.xml-things for you. the only files you _probably_ need to copy manually, are the native plugin files. In case of android this is the file in `cordova-plugin-datepicker/src/android`. Copy the native files into the plugins-directory which i think is `platforms/android/src/com/phonegap/plugins` for android. if the files are in their correct place, datepicker's `show`-method should simply present the native datepicker dialog.

Comment: Yes, all the files are correctly copied. In that case then I might not be invoking the `show` method correctly. Do you know how could I bind a datepicker to specific input field? (noob question)

Comment: bind a click handler to that input field, invoking the show-method. in show's callback, take the result (the date which was picked by the user) and write it to the input field. pretty standard stuff :P

Comment: hm, I have done it, similar to this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601760/android-phonegap-app-angularjs-update-scope-with-selected-date-on-android-da but now I can see in my eclipse that the application is complaining that `show` function is not defined. It seems that I should have included something more.I have tried with including DatePicker.js into my index.html (which I have found in /plugins/com.plugin.datepicker/www/android/DatePicker.js),but it still doesn't seem it is finding a show action, even though I can see that plugin has been set up inside my config.xml in `platforms`

Comment: you need to call `datePicker.show(...)`, right? so is `datePicker` defined? if not, then the plugin is not installed correctly. forget about index.html, you don't need to include the .js files manually, as cordova automatically loads the plugin (DatePicker.js in your case) at runtime.

Comment: Hm, it is possible that it hasn't been correctly installed. I will investigate and get back here.